# BarButtonItem resizing for unknown reason

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have a button that is initialized like that>

```
self.button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                                                            target:self 
                                                            action:@selector(doAction)];
```

Later, I am attaching a custom background to it, like that>

```
    [self.button  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customNavBar_button_right_enabled"] 
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and puting it onto navbar.

```
   [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.button 
                                     animated:NO];
```

This image has fixed size. I want that button to have fully custom background image with no "intelligent" resizing  with UIEdgeInsets.I don't want any resizing. But for some reason, it behaves like its insets would be active and it is resized to have bigger width, with roughly the middle half of picture considerably stretched to provide for the wider button.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve a bar button item with a custom image is by:

1. Drag a UIButton onto the storyboard.
2. Set the button Type to Custom and set your image for that button.
3. Drag the button onto your Toolbar.

The storyboard automatically creates a UIBarButtonItem and adds your UIButton as a subview. Or if you do NOT want to use storyboards you could implement the following:

```
// Initialize the UIButton
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"];
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

// Initialize the UIBarButtonItem
UIBarButtonItem aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

// Set the Target and Action for aButton
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Do not forget to add the aBarButtonItem to the UIToolbar.

Comment: I went with programatic approach, storyboards are too rigid if you need flexibility in UI layout management. The problem is the solution solves getting the picture there, but creates more problems elsewhere, at least for now. I have code elsewhere that relies on the fact, that the button is a UIBarButtonSystemItem, not UIButton.
But maybe I will overcome it.
I figured if I can't get rid of built-in cap insets, then it would be better to set them to zeros explicitly.